# Ошибки при попытке изменить запись в Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot

В модальное окно вывожу данные одной записи для редактирования. При нажатии на кнопку "Save" получаю ошибку. Возвращается пустой объект я так понял. Подскажите пожалуйста где я допустил ошибку?

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/classifier")
public class ClassifierController {

    private final LuServices luServices;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public ClassifierController(LuServices luServices, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.luServices = luServices;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String showClassifierPage(Model model) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        PersonDetails personDetails = (PersonDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        
        model.addAttribute("personDetails", personDetails);
        model.addAttribute("basicLu", luServices.findBasicLU());
        model.addAttribute("newBasicLu", new Lu());

        return "lu/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveBasicLu", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String saveBasicLu(Lu lu) {
        luServices.addNewBasicLu(lu);
        return "redirect:/classifier";
    }

    @GetMapping("/oneBasicLu")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Lu> getBasicLuById(Integer id) {
        return luServices.findByID(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateBasicLu", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String updateBasicLu(Lu lu) {
        System.out.println(lu); //Тут объект с пустыми полями получаю
        luServices.updateBasicLu(lu);
        return "redirect:/classifier";
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/css/style.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/css/awesome/all.css}"/>
    <title>Главная страница</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page_wrapper">

    <div class="container_resizer">
        <div class="container-left">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addModal">Add new</button>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="custom_scrollbar card-block">
                    <table id="resizableTable" class="basicLuTable app_table table_resizable">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Наименование</th>
                            <th>Системный код</th>
                            <th>Код</th>
                            <th>Действия</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr th:each ="itemBasicLu :${basicLu}">
                            <td th:text="${itemBasicLu.id}"></td>
                            <td th:text ="${itemBasicLu.text}"></td>
                            <td th:text ="${itemBasicLu.lcode}"></td>
                            <td th:text ="${itemBasicLu.code}"></td>
                            <td>
                                <a th:href="@{classifier/oneBasicLu/(id=${itemBasicLu.id})}" class="btn btn-primary editLuButton"
                                   data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editModal">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <ul id="table_menu" class="container__menu container__menu--hidden"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editBasicLuModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <form th:action="@{/classifier/updateBasicLu}" method="put">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="editBasicLuModalLabel">Edit Lu</h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="idEdit" class="col-form-label">Id:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idEdit" disabled>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="textEdit" class="col-form-label">Text:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textEdit">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="lcodeEdit" class="col-form-label">Lcode:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lcodeEdit">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="codeEdit" class="col-form-label">Code:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codeEdit">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



</div>

<footer>
    Footer
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/test.js}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.basicLuTable .editLuButton').on('click', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();

       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       $.get(href, function (itemBasicLu, status) {
           $('#idEdit').val(itemBasicLu.id);
           $('#textEdit').val(itemBasicLu.text);
           $('#lcodeEdit').val(itemBasicLu.lcode);
           $('#codeEdit').val(itemBasicLu.code);
       });
    });
});
```

Сервис

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class LuServices {
    private final LuRepository repository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public LuServices(LuRepository repository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public List<Lu> findBasicLU() {
        return repository.findByTag(0);
    }

    public Optional<Lu> findByID(int id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addNewBasicLu(Lu lu) {
        lu.setCreatedate(LocalDateTime.now());
        lu.setUpdatedate(LocalDateTime.now());
        lu.setStatus(1);
        lu.setTag(0);
        repository.save(lu);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateBasicLu(Lu lu) {
        lu.setCreatedate(LocalDateTime.now());
        lu.setUpdatedate(LocalDateTime.now());
        lu.setStatus(1);
        lu.setTag(0);
        repository.save(lu);
    }
}
```

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите что уходит в консоли браузера. У тега `input` не вижу атрибута `name`. Что за файл test.js, это для тестирования или для использования в работе приложения?

Comment: Файл test.js содержит скрипт для вывода данных редактируемого объекта в поля input. При открытии модального окна в консоли выводятся правильные данные редактируемого объекта. А вот как посмотреть что передается при нажатии на кнопку "Save" не знаю.. С JS особо не знаком, а в контроллере получаю объект и пустыми полями.

Comment: Добавьте `name` аналогично id для тега input. Консоль в браузере хром,  F12 -> Network (вкладка в открывшемся окошке)

Comment: Добавил, в консоли вроде передаваться стали параметры, но ошибка осталась. В вопрос добавил скрин ошибки.

Comment: В методе `updateBasicLu` у Lu не хватает [аннотации @ModelAttribute](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial#the-controller)

Comment: Я так тоже пробовал public String updateBasicLu(@ModelAttribute("lu") Lu lu). Не работает и так пробовал public String updateBasicLu(@ModelAttribute("itemBasicLu") Lu lu). В видеоуроке, по которому я пытался реализовать этого атрибута не было совсем.

Comment: Вроде понял причину. input для id у меня был disabled. Я специально так сделал, чтобы пользователь не менял его. Хотелось бы конечно чтобы без id была возможность редактировать

Comment: Тогда уж лучше `readonly` использовать, в запрос такое поле отправится.

Comment: Спасибо, так лучше. А вообще приведенный мною пример изменения записи через модальное окно приемлем или есть варианты получше?

Comment: Если делать со строгим рендером на стороне сервера, то должна быть отдельная страница вместо модального окна и соответствующий метод в контроллере.  Можно использовать [SPA стиль без перезагрузки страницы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) , у меня в проекте этим занимается отдельный разработчик. В текущем виде для работы приложения этого достаточно.

Comment: Отдельные страницы для  добавления, редактирования не хочется делать. Модальные окна мне кажется позволяют создать дружелюбный интерфейс.

Comment: А где почитать подробнее про  SPA, может это то что мне нужно

Comment: Пока не изучите спринг, не стоит браться за spa, т.к. фреймверки очень быстро меняются и за пол года уже по другому будете воспринимать. [Основные React, Angular, Vue.js](https://habr.com/ru/post/476312/) , а с появлением typescript порог вхождения еще немного поднялся. Может еще что-то есть на jQuery, но его давно не использовал.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.